# using the sum function to add points on a caretsian plane

Tags: python-3.x, oop, sum

The code is giving me an error. It's supposed to add points on a Cartesian plane.

```
class Cluster(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.center = Point(x, y)
        self.points = []

    def update(self):
        sum_ = sum(self.points, Point(0, 0))
        len_ = float(len(self.points))
        self.center = Point(sum_.x/len_, sum_.y/len_)
        self.points = []

    def add_point(self, point):
        self.points.append(point)

 sum_ = sum(self.points, Point(0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sum()` function only only works for types which support addition. A class can implement addition using the `__add__` function. If this is indeed the problem you are facing, define in your `Point` class a function like:

```py
class Point:
     # ...
     def __add__(self, other):
         return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```